# Dynamic object throwing 'does not contain definition for...' exception when member exists in collection

Tags: c#, dynamic, xamarin.android, expandoobject

I am having an issue with this piece of code:

```
IList<dynamic> list = await GetApiUrl("EndpointName").GetJsonListAsync(); // Call to API using FLUrl

List<Model> modelList = new List<Model>();
foreach(var item in list) 
{
    var model = new Model() 
    {
        GuidId = new Guid(item.Id),
        Name = item.Name
    }

    modelList.Add(model);
}

public class Model 
{
    public Guid GuidId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Sample API response:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "9232f70b-bdc6-402c-9fab-250977e9a0c1",
        "Name": "Sample name"
    },
    {
        "Id": "0f746670-e057-4c13-9a82-c98419d09e55",
        "Name": "Sample name"
    },
    {
        "Id": "370cce64-37f6-4e71-a44e-32168c3ef2cb",
        "Name": "Sample name"
    }
]
```

I get this exception when accessing `item.Id` or `item.Name` even though I have confirmed that item object does have `Id` and `Name` members (see attached image below).

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 
''System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'Id''
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Id` and `Name` are values of the `Keys` property, not properties themselves. Why do you have a dynamic object anyway, why not deserialize straight to `Model`?

Comment: Yeah, they are values of `Keys` collection but shouldn't dynamic object return value for a key (if one exists) when used with member access operator `.`?


I have IList<dynamic> because that is what FLUrl extension is returning when GetJsonListAsync() is called on IFlurlRequest. Refer to source code:
https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/d278275acb259f23a87df226bd03cb18c57927b9/src/Flurl.Http/GeneratedExtensions.cs#L101

Comment: Actually, yes you are right. It works for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rLKimg

Comment: @Crowcoder do you have any idea why is my code not working then?

Comment: No, I'm trying to think of something but I got nothing.

Comment: @Crowcoder I have extended your code to match this sample and it is working...I am even more confused now. 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/HhVzhU

Comment: Turn it off an back on? I made a Visual Studio project and it works perfectly. Make sure you have no warnings in the project references.

Comment: @TipsyFingers Test the code and it works as well. You could try to delete the bin and obj folder and clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT please referr to my answer below for more details about what I've found out about this issue. Cleaning the project does not help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found what was causing the issue but it is rather wierd.

The code is part of Xamarin.Android application and since I started working on the project, exception settings in IDE were wierd to me because all exceptions had 'Break when this exception happens' disabled. Yesterday (cuz I was sick of digging through files to find where the exception was thrown) I have enabled that checkbox in order to see see where exception was thrown in runtime along with exception details.

I had an enlightenment when I started the app without debugging and it actually worked (eventhough exception was still being thrown). Then I remembered what I did yesterday and reverted exception settings in IDE and, TA DAAA, it worked.

**I guess this has something to do with Xamarin and the way it handles exceptions. If someone can elaborate on this behavior I will be happy to accept his/her answer**

Comment: I almost asked you to try it without debugging but it didn't happen when I debugged so I didn't ask. I came across a blog or SO question that mentioned it when I was googling but I closed it.